# Find out if files in a folder exist under other name in other folder

Tags: linux, shell-script, filenames, bsd

*Possibly a little incorrect English ahead:*

There are at least 2 folders. For this, **A** contains files without extension, usually usernames, and **B** contains similar files, with '.yml' extension or possibly without extension, or even other extension, that's not always the case.

How to find out if the files in the **A** folder exist in **B**, possibly under a different extension, without using scripting language such as Python ? It'd not be much of an issue for me to make a Python script, but for portability I'd prefer shell scripting, which I suck at. Not to mention I don't know all the commands.

It's only good if this can be done in non-Linux systems too, particularly BSD.

***EDIT 0:*** The difference in name isn't always just the extension, the name could have characters before or after the same text. For example, if **A** had a file called `foobar`, it could be named `location_foobar` in **B**. Otherwise the name wouldn't be more different, like `foo1bar`, that's entirely different thing, so the script wouldn't be looking for such differences.

Comment: Welcome here! What do you mean when you write "possibly under a different extension or even a name"? Do you mean that the file may have a different name in the two folders? You should clarify that point because it's a huge difference to compare files by _names_ and by _content_.

Comment: Why can't you use a scripting language? Python or Perl should be available almost everywhere.

Comment: @vonbrand: Portability and doing it with tools most basically available. Perl and Python aren't marked mandatory whilst Bash/Dash or other compatible is.

Comment: what do you mean by "at least"? Can there be C, D, etc. and do they matter?

Comment: I answered assuming that you wanted to match files by name, apparently that's not what you want. Are you looking for files with identical content? Or for hard links? Or are you looking for a name that contains the name in A as a substring (e.g. `A/gil` matches `B/virgil42`)?

Comment: @Gilles: Filename in B which can contain, or match, the filename in A. If I were to do this in Python, I'd simply use the language's ability to look at a string and find the source string in it anywhere, assuming the source string isn't changed in target string at all.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Yes, in this hierarchy the similar filenames, assuming the details in `EDIT 0`, can occur in different folders, and that's not changeable. If the different folders' files had nothing in common regarding the filename, there's no way to connect them.

Comment: @Gilles, addendum: It might sound conflicting, but I'll need that ability eventually. `gil` in `vergil34` isn't quite correct matching when talking about filenames with fixed similarities, but I'll look at the results before doing.

Comment: Are you looking for identical files? Would an md5 approach make sense?

Comment: Is it the language (Python) that is the restriction or is scripting in general (Bash, Ksh, Perl, ...) not allowed?

Comment: @terdon: The contents are different at 100% certainty, but the filenames have fixed similarities.

Comment: @Anthon: I -could- do it in Python, but I want to use shell scripting using the standard shells, Bash and such, cuz that's always available.

Comment: @rautamiekka I asked because I call things in Python a program, and in bash a script. Therefore my first reaction was "Is the OP asking for C program" if it cannot be Python or (bash) scripting? ;-)

Comment: @Anthon: I'm not sure what you mean, but there's the 'shell-script' tag, and I say 'without using a scripting language such as Python', cuz Python has really easy syntax for checking strings, whereas most of the NIX shell scripting language doesn't make much any sense, which is why I'm failing to learn it, which is why I have to get help from someone else than myself, but knowing that sometimes even Python, or Perl, aren't installed and I don't have the power to install, I have to bite the bullet and use what I get as standard stock, which is shell scripting. Note that I'm not even that ...

Comment: ... great at Window$ scripting using Batch than I'm at NIX shell scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple matter to write a shell script that loops over the files of one directory and find if there are files with a superstring as their name in another directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
dirA=$1
dirB=$2
for x in "$dirA/"*; do
  base_name="${x##*/}"
  set -- "$dirB"/*"$base_name"*
  if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    for y; do
      echo "$base_name found in B as ${y##*/}"
    done
  else
    echo "$x not found in B"
  fi
done
```

This is portable to any Bourne/POSIX-style shell (`sh`, ash, bash, ksh, …). Some shell constructs used:

- `#!/bin/sh`: the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top of every script
- `$1`, `$2`: the two arguments to pass to the script, A and B
- `${x##*/}` is the value of `x` minus the longest prefix of the form `*/`, i.e. `$x` minus everything up to the last `/`, i.e. `${x##*/}` is the part of `$x` after the last `/`.
- `set -- "B/${x##*/}."*` sets the positional parameters to the list of matching files in B. If there are no matches, the pattern is left unexpanded, so this sets the first positional parameter to a string ending in `.*`.
- `for y; do` loops over the positional parameters.

Comment: See my `EDIT 0` on the OP.

Comment: Suggestion: Add variables for the folders so that the script doesn't need editing to match the folder names.

Comment: @rautamiekka I've changed my answer to match your updated question.

Comment: The script does do what it's asked to.